# Forum mysql joins

Tags: mysql

I want to make a simple forum and I have 3 tables:

```
`forum_forum_topic` (
  `id`,
  `forum_slug`,
  `slug`
  ...
)

`forum_user` (
  `id`,
  `role`,
  `email`,
  `pass`,
  `name`
)

`forum_forum_topic_message` (
  `id`,
  `forum_topic_id,
  `forum_slug` ,
  `user_id`,
  `message`,
  `created_at`,
  `updated_at`,
)
```

And I want to get all the topics with user info AND last post in that forum. So now I have this query:

```
SELECT ft . * , u.name
FROM forum_forum_topic ft
LEFT JOIN forum_user u ON u.id = ft.user_id
WHERE ft.forum_slug = "general-discussions"
ORDER BY ft.created_at DESC
```

Now I get forum topics and user who created them in one query (one row per topic), is it possible to get last message info in that topic row (with user info)?
e.g.

```
id  forum_slug              title   status  views   slug    user_id     post_count  created_at  updated_at  name         last_post_id last_post_user_name last_post_time
43  general-discussions     hallo   NULL    0       hallo   11          2           1316445710  0           another_user 5             user               12312411
42  general-discussions     hi      NULL    0       hi      9           6           1316440635  0           user         12            another_user       141414
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking about this solution... i did not test. Anyway, it may not be the best as it's slow...

```
SELECT ft . * , u.name, 
(select message from forum_forum_topic_message where user_id = u.id order by updated_at desc limit 1) as     'last_message'
FROM forum_forum_topic ft
LEFT JOIN forum_user u ON u.id = ft.user_id
WHERE ft.forum_slug = "general-discussions"
ORDER BY ft.created_at DESC
```

EDIT: added conditon : "where user_id = u.id"

Comment: But it only gives me the same last_message for ALL topics.. I want to show last messages from different topics.

Comment: yes, sorry, try to add into the subselect condition to match the user, i forgot that. I just edited the post... though i'm not sure if you can access the user table from subselect...

Comment: Hm, no, that doesn't work as it only gives message which are posted by topic author.